# Overruling htaccess line

Tags: php, .htaccess

I got a content page where content is dynamically loaded. I use htaccess for this, to make sure every page that ends with .html becomes a correct content page.

With this line:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*).html /content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

I want to do the same with a landingspage, but because of the line above it always redirects to the content page instead of the landingspage.

```
RewriteRule    ^advies/(.*).html _lp.php?trefwoord=$1 [L]
```

The above line does only work when I remove the first one.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^advies/(.+)\.html$ _lp.php?trefwoord=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /content.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

i.e. keep the generic rule at the end.